# A simple inequality question

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be positive real numbers such that $$a+b=c+d=e+f$$ along with the condition that $$a>c>e$$ and $$b<d<f$$ Is it possible that $c^2<ae$ and $d^2<bf$ are both satisfied simultaneously? The examples that I have generated suggest that this is not possible. However, I cannot find a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the common sum with $S$:
$$
 S = a+b=c+d=e+f
$$
and assume that $c^2<ae$ and $d^2<bf$ are both satisfied.
Then, using the 
inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean:
$$
 S = c + d < \sqrt{ae} + \sqrt{bf} \le \frac{a+e}{2} +  \frac{b+f}{2} = S
$$
which is a contradiction.

Note that the conditions $a>c>e$ and $b<d<f$
are not needed for the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be possible and $a+b=c+d=e+f=k$.

Thus, $k>a$ and $$(k-c)^2<(k-a)(k-e)$$ or
$$c^2<ae+k(2c-a-e).$$

If $c\geq\frac{a+e}{2}$ then by AM-GM
$$c^2<ae\leq\left(\frac{a+e}{2}\right)^2\leq c^2,$$
which is a contradiction.

It est, $c<\frac{a+e}{2}$ and $$c^2<ae+k(2c-a-e)<ae+a(2c-a-e),$$
which gives $$a^2+c^2<2ac$$ or
$$(a-c)^2<0,$$ which is a contradiction again.

We got that it's impossible.

Done!

Comment: How do you get $(k-c)^2<(k-a)(k-e)$? Take $a=5, c=4, e=3, k=8$ for e.g.

Comment: @Macavity It's $d^2<bf$. See please better my solution.

Comment: @Macavity Thank you! I thought about you badly. It seems that this is not true. Excuse me.

Comment: You’re welcome. Usually I try to state where I disagree, but try to keep emotion out of it. Sometimes it works.